# How can I do a insert a new Date with Spring Data MongoDB?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

How can I insert new Date with Spring Data MongoDB?

I'm currently resorting to

```
User = new User();
user.setCreationDate(new Date());
mongoOperation.save(user);
```

to solve the problem, but the end result is that a user is saved with the current time of the server that is running the code, instead of the current time of the server that is running the database.

Since this code will run in several instances on several servers in parallel, and the servers might have slightly different times, I'd like to replicate the exact same behaviour I would get from doing a

```
db.users.insert({'creationDate': new ISODate()})
```

diretly in the mongo shell.

How can this be achieved with Sprint-Data-MongoDB?

Comment: Why are your dates different? I mean you would for sure need to set the correct timezone & locale on your servers...but even then, the date _value_ should be the same, it would only be displayed differently in UI based on the locale you choose to when formatting

Comment: Hey @Zilvinas, thanks for joining in.
The dates _could_ be different because they are completely different date calculations... one is provided by the mongoDb engine, the other is provided by java. 
I'm sure the servers are configured as best as possible (I have no access to them other than by deploy pipeline, they're handled by infra/dev-ops solely), but since I'm storing with ms precision, there could be discrepancies...

Still, even if java's new Date() is good enought, I'd still would like to know how to do it :)

Comment: If your servers are started having locale and server time set, the atomic date & time on different servers should be the same having in mind the timezone info. If server 1 located at GMT+2:00 shows time 2 PM, then server 2 located at GMT-3:00 should show 9 AM, but the atomic time value should be the same. Meaning that you use the *locale* value when printing out date / time to the user, so if you would use the same locale on both servers when outputting time, it should show exactly the same value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can achieve this consistently by using spring-data audit feature

In order to enable auditing we need to add **< mongo:auditing/ >** tag to Spring configuration.

Auditing let you declaratively tell Spring to store:

- date when the document has been created: `@CreatedDate`
- date when the document has been updated last time: `@LastModifiedDate`
- the user who has created the document: `@CreatedBy`
- the user who has done the most recent update: `@LastModifiedBy`
- current document version: `@Version`

For our use case if we combine javax.persistence jar date style and mongodb auditing we get new ISODate() always by using the following declaration

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP) 
@DateTimeFormat(style = "M-") 
@CreatedDate
private Date createdDate;
```

This way you can create new Date using spring-data-mongodb

Answer (score 1):

```
@Column(updatable = false)
    @CreationTimestamp
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;
```

We provide @CreatedDate to capture the user who created the entity as well as @LastModifiedDate to capture when the change happened.

Spring Data JPA Documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#auditing.annotations

Comment: You may want to add more details to explain the rationale, although other answer has been selected as the solution.

Comment: Thank you, I will do. @azbarcea

Comment: the question is about Spring Data MongoDB, your answer is about Spring Data JPA. Are you sure that your code is compatible with mongodb?